Network (failed)net::ERR_FAILED with larger data responses
I have a service calling my spring boot application endpoint that expects an Observable with responseType: 'blob' as 'json'. The spring application returns HttpServletResponse's outputstream. If the output stream returns data size high enough, the network status in dev tools (Chrome and Edge) will update with (failed)net::ERR_FAILED and no response. This occurs in local and in our UAT/prod environments.
It seems as though once the stream size reaches a certain point, the network connection errors out but the spring application will continue to run.
8KB downloads fine, but 1k KB produces the error.
How do I allow Angular to allow the larger files?
I've tried updating spring to write to a new ByteArrayOutputStream, and convert and return that as a ResponseEntity<byte[]> but this has the same response.
Many results I find point to CORS request issues, but the spring application already allows this. In addition, I've imported the fetch request to Postman with successful results, so this seems like Angular's issue.
Another post suggested proxy config set up in Angular, but this is already set up as
secure: false, changeOrigin: true
I've tried using Chrome's netlog viewer but not seeing anything stand out:
...
t=10729 [st=7194]      HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t=10729 [st=7194]      URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                       --> byte_count = 7
t=10729 [st=7194]      HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t=10729 [st=7194]      URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                       --> byte_count = 46951
t=10729 [st=7194]      HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=36]
t=10765 [st=7230]      URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                       --> byte_count = 8096
t=10765 [st=7230]      HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=17]
t=10782 [st=7247] -CORS_REQUEST
t=10782 [st=7247]  CANCELLED
t=10783 [st=7248] -REQUEST_ALIVE


is there any error in the browser console?

Yes, it looks like the POST initiator stack trace.
POST https://uat.com/my/api net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
Then a list of next/(anonymous) polyfills/main.js
